# Using cut to manipulate a text file

Tags: text-processing, cut

I am having trouble manipulating the text in the screenshot. I need to change the file so only the IP address in the last column are left. [image]

Comment: post input fragment as a text, not as image

Comment: `awk '{print $NF}' file`

Comment: [PSA: Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/135943)

Answer (score 1):

`cut` is a bit annoying in that even if you set the delimiter to a space, it takes *all* spaces as delimiters. It'll find a large bunch of empty fields in that input...

You could use `cut -cN-M` with appropriate values to pick a fixed-width field, or `awk '{print $5}'` to print the fifth field (`awk` takes multiple spaces as as one delimiter). Or you could use something like `sed -e 's/^.*A[[:space:]]*//'` to remove everything up to the (last) `A`, along with the following white space...

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I'll give them a try at work tomorrow. Sorry about the screenshot, but this is my first time on here.

Comment: Thanks guys! The awk command worked very nicely for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

A simple awk command:

```
awk '{print $NF}' file
```

will print the last field ($NF) of the `file`.